# Shelling out to command on path without showing a new window

Tags: .net, f#, f#-fake

I'm trying to replace a rake script with a FAKE one, but am running into some problems shelling out to another application. In rake I'd do something like `sh 'bundle exec jekyll "#{outputDir}"'` where `bundle` is on my `PATH`, but in .NET/FAKE I can't get the command to run without popping up a new window.

My specific use case is for FAKE and its [ProcessHelper](http://fsharp.github.io/FAKE/apidocs/fake-processhelper.html), but I think this question can be generalised to any use of [ProcessStartInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

The following runs the command successfully (`info` is a `ProcessStartInfo`), but pops up a new window:

```
ExecProcess (fun info -> 
                   info.UseShellExecute <- true
                   info.CreateNoWindow <- true //doesn't apply when UseShellExecute is true
                   info.FileName <- "bundle"
                   info.WorkingDirectory <- workingDir
                   info.Arguments <- "exec jekyll \"" + outputDir + "")
            (TimeSpan.FromMinutes 5.)
```

To reuse the current window I set `UseShellExecute` to `false`, but then the "bundle" command isn't found ("Exception: start of process bundle failed. The system cannot find the file specified"). I'm guessing that without `UseShellExecute` the `PATH` environment is not set, hence my attempt at calling `setEnvironmentVariables`:

```
let pathEnv = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH")
ExecProcess (fun info -> 
                   info.UseShellExecute <- false
                   info.FileName <- "bundle"
                   info.WorkingDirectory <- workingDir
                   info.Arguments <- "exec jekyll \"" + outputDir + "")
                   setEnvironmentVariables info [("PATH", pathEnv)])
            (TimeSpan.FromMinutes 5.)
```

Is there a way to configure `ProcessStartInfo` to do what I'm after? Or is there an alternative to `ProcessStartInfo` I should be using?

Comment: I would guess that when shellExecute is false you don't need the `exec` and can just call jekyll directly.

Comment: @JohnPalmer I think it still needs to run through bundler, but the exact command isn't important. Shelling out to `ruby -e "puts 'hello'"` where `ruby` is on the path could be used as an equivalent case.

Comment: It seems like this is covered fairly clearly at [CreateNoWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.createnowindow.aspx) and [UseShellExecute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.useshellexecute.aspx).  You need to set the latter to false for the former to take effect, but then you need to use the full path (the WorkingDirectory property is not used to locate the executable).

Comment: @kvb - yes, I was hoping there was a way to locate the program via the path environment variable. I maybe have to just manually search the path.

Comment: So this is not a FAKE issue, right? Does it work from any other .NET program?

Comment: @forki23 Correct, this is not a FAKE issue. It just came up porting a build script to FAKE.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find a way to do this, so ended up manually searching the path.

```
let findExecutableInPath (exe:String) =
    Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH").Split([| Path.PathSeparator |])
    |> Seq.append ["."]
    |> Seq.map (fun p -> p @@ exe)
    |> Seq.tryFind (File.Exists)
```

I'll see if this is something that will fit in with FAKE.

(Converted to community wiki in case anyone has a better idea :))